# How to access objects in Jekyll array?

Tags: arrays, object, jekyll, liquid

My Jekyll page code is as following (*simplified*):

**_layouts/content.html:**

```
---
layout: null
---
<pre>
    {{ content }}
</pre>
```

**any_page.md**

```
---
layout: content
social:
    - twitter :
        url : "https://twitter.com"
        user : "foo"
        show : true
    - instagram : 
        url : "https://instagram.com"
        user : "bar"
        show : false
---
```

My understanding of above in any_page.md is

- `social` is an `array` of objects having items 0, 1; `social[0]` equals to * `twitter`. These keys can be variable.
- each array item in above array is `social[i]`; an object having similar known keys (url, user, show)

**Problem:**

How to access page.social[i]["url"] & other two known keys?
How to access these known keys of an object residing in a variable-length array?
How to get the following outputs: `twitter`, `https://twitter.com`, `foo`, `true`

**Code I have tried:**

all social array: `{{ page.social }}` outputs *(as expected)*

```
  {“twitter”=>
    { “url”=>”https://twitter.com”,
      “user”=>”foo”,
      “show”=>true
    }
  }
  {“instagram”=>
    { “url”=>”https://instagram.com”,
      “user”=>”bar”,
      “show”=>false
    }
  }
```

social array's first object: `{{ page.social[0] }}` outputs *(as expected)*

```
{“twitter”=>
    { “url”=>”https://twitter.com”,
      “user”=>”foo”,
      “show”=>true
    }
  }
```

Failed attempts to access `url` of item 01 (all results to empty):

```
{{ page.social[0]["url"] }}  
{{ page.social[0][url] }}  
{{ page.social[0]."url" }}  
{{ page.social[0].url }}  
{{ page.social[0][0] }}
```

Addendum:

I have also tried the for loop; & it gives all the values on root level (twitter etc..), but no access to the object keys:

```
{% for item in page.social %}  
    item = {{ item }}                # works
    item[URL] = {{ item[url] }}      # empty
    item["URL"] = {{ item["url"] }}  # empty
    item."URL" = {{ item."url" }}    # empty
    item.URL = {{ item.url }}        # empty
    i = {{forloop.index }}           # ok, but starts from 1 instead of 0
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will work:

```
twitter key: {{page.social[0]|first|first}} 
<h2>data</h2>
url: {{page.social[0]['twitter'].url}}
user: {{page.social[0]['twitter'].user}}
show: {{page.social[0]['twitter'].show}}
```

## Another approach

```
social:
  twitter :
     url : "https://twitter.com"
     user : "foo"
     show : true
  instagram : 
     url : "https://instagram.com"
     user : "bar"
     show : false
```

Then you can access it with:

```
{% for item in page.social%}
key: {{item[0]}}<br>
{% endfor %}
<hr>
<h2>data</h2>
url: {{page.social['twitter'].url}}
user: {{page.social['twitter'].user}}
show: {{page.social['twitter'].show}}
```

Comment: Thanks, I would appreciate if you explain als how my deceleration was causing problems & how the omission of `-` made the difference?

Comment: Both works but the way you define data changes the way you access it, read more here: http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html .

Answer (score 6):

I have accepted [marcanuy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1165509/marcanuy)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46960601/1333228), here I am just documenting what I used based on his answer;

```
{% for item in page.social %}  # OUTPUT for 1st item
    {{ item[0] }}              # twitter:
    {{ item[1].url }}          # https://twitter.com
    {{ item[1].user }}         # foo
    {{ item[1].show }}         # true
  {% endfor %}
```

Also, the declaration in front matter is bit changed. The one which works with above code is:

```
social:
  twitter :
     url : "https://twitter.com"
     user : "foo"
     show : true
  instagram : 
     url : "https://instagram.com"
     user : "bar"
     show : false
```

- Note the missing `-` dashes. Although both ways are correct, I need to read more to how to access both.
- As mentioned at http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html, indentations & `-` matter. Each item having more spaces than earlier makes itself child of earlier.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for that ;)

Comment: this is much insightful!